# WCF Service exception: {"Could not resolve subject key identifier"}

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, wcf-security, ws-security

I am trying to communicate with a service with the WCF framework. The only security information I have available is:

- Key identifier type: Binary Security Token / X.509 certificate
- Signature algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
- Signature canonicalization: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
- Digest algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1

The certificate is a P12 certificate with a private key, imported in the localComputer Root key store.

I got a succesful transaction working in SoapUI, and I managed to get the Soap XML message:

**SoapUI message:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="*removed*">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-*removed*">*removed*</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-37" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-36">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>*removed*</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          *removed*
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-*removed*">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-*removed*">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-*removed*" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-36" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <!--Not important-->
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have been through numerous exceptions and security setups, and now I have arrived at a CustomBinding with an AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement. This is the closest I can get to the succesful SoapUI message in WCF:

**WCF message:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
          <Reference URI="#_2">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
            <DigestValue>*removed*</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>*removed*</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier">*removed*</o:KeyIdentifier>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!--Not important-->
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

SoapUI has some security setting which needed to be Binary security token, instead of X509 certificate.
I also changed the DNS value of the EndPoint in the app.config so it would not complain about a different DNS claim in the certificate :S

```
<identity>
  <dns value="*IPv4-address*" />
</identity>
```

My EndPoint behavior is like this:

```
<behavior name="CustomBehavior">
  <clientCredentials>
    <clientCertificate findValue="*IPv4-address*" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"/>
    <serviceCertificate>
      <defaultCertificate findValue="*IPv4-address*" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"/>
    </serviceCertificate>
  </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

The customBinding in C#:

```
var asymmetricSecurityBindingElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
asymmetricSecurityBindingElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
asymmetricSecurityBindingElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
asymmetricSecurityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;

CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
customBinding.Elements.Add(asymmetricSecurityBindingElement);
customBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));

HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
customBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
```

The remote service throws an exception when executing a WSDL method: {"Could not resolve subject key identifier"} (innerException) http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13983_01/troubleshooting.htm says the public key certificate might be missing in the remote service keystore, but the SoapUI transaction works. It also mentions something about an alias, and I am not sure what this means.

I do not seem to have a clue to resolve my issue. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this binding](https://gist.github.com/yaronn/6775810):

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
            <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" includeTimestamp="false"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                <secureConversationBootstrap />
            </security>
            <httpTransport />
        </binding>
</customBinding>
```

make sure to decorate your contract to sign only:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName=..., ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
```

More information [here](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. And I have indeed used your very helpful blog about common pitfalls ;). I have the Sign protectionlevel set up correctly and I tried your customBinding with httpsTransport which results in another exception: "Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings." Even though my binding is now set up as the last pitfall mentioned in your post.

Comment: check this post http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2010/10/wcf-cannot-find-token-authenticator.html